# Smarty concat string to variable to get another variable

Tags: php, smarty

Hi I would like to concat a string into a variable to retrieve the value of another variable let say the example is below

```
# Variable one
filter_var = "The value to get"
name = "var"

# now I want to retrieve the value of filter_var. What I was thinking is something like this
{{ "filter_".name }} # assuming "name" variable has dynamic content
```

How do I solve this?

Edit:

Another sample is below

```
traduction.Product = "the value"
categorie = "Product"

# Now I'm trying to output the value in a div tag
<div>{{ traduction.{{categorie}} }}</div>
```

but I'm getting an error of Expected name or number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Smarty 3, you can use this:

```
{$filter_{$name}}
```

It's mentioned in the "Variable variables" section on this page: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl